# Jquery Date Picker - dateformat output divers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm experiencing a problem with Jquery Date picker. Even though I set the dateFormat to dd/mm/yy (e.g. 26/06/1985), i still get some responses without slashes like 26061985 or with "-" like 26-06-1985. I seemed to have formatted the date properly but everything still points to the formatting being skewed. Here's my code:

```
        <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true,
                    yearRange: '-100y:c+nn',
                    defaultDate: '-21y',
                    maxDate: '-16y',
                    onSelect: function(){
                        console.log('revalidate');
                        $('#downloadform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'extravraag4');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Any suggestions?

With kind regards,

~Lex

Comment: Hi guys, an update: I've found it the problem MIGHT be related to the use of iPad in combination with Safari 8/9.

Comment: "some responses"...means what? Using the datepicker doesn't necessarily prevent the user from typing something else into the related textbox instead.